# How can I stop the left alt key opening the application menu on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed with GNOME.

My <kbd>left alt</kbd> key opens application menu while <kbd>right alt</kbd> works as expected (<kbd>left alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> doesn't work for example, <kbd>right alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> works perfectly).

How can I fix the <kbd>left alt</kbd> behavior so that it works like <kbd>right alt</kbd>?

Comment: i'm not sure you really want the same behavior between left and right `Alt`; the right isn't called `Alt Gr` for nothing, it's because he has a behavior that the basic `Alt` hasn't; for example, if `Alt Gr` would have the same behavior as `Alt`, on an azerty keyboard, we couldn't type characters like '@', '{' or '#' (and i'm pretty sure it can't be possible to type some character too on a qwerty keyboard) and think about the character which can be displayed by typing the ASCII code

Comment: See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146 for a bug regarding `Alt+Left` and `Alt+Right`. The fix is: `sudo kbd_mode -s`

Answer (score 1):

The terms we are discussing here are "keyboard shortcuts" and "keybindings". They are useful when searching for help.

First, run `xev` in a terminal to see if the key works.
If it works, open **Settings > Devices > Keyboard** for a list of shortcuts. If it says **Alt** without specifying right or left they should both work. Replace any that specify a side and make sure it only says Alt.

If you have trouble making the settings do that, install dconf-editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

and launch it from the terminal

```
dconf-editor
```

Locate the search icon and type `keybinding` and look through the paths for what you need. In your example navigate to

```
org/gnome/desktop/vm/keybindings/close
```

If the default value is on it should be set to

```
['<Alt>F4']
```

If it's not, switch default to off and enter exactly the above as a custom entry.

My Alt shortcuts seem to be the same for each side, so maybe yours got reconfigured somehow.

Comment: Close combination is set to`['<Alt>F4']`, but on alt press window losts focus. If restore focus (click in window) `F4` works and closes window.

Comment: What happens when you quickly tap left Alt and nothing else? What happens when you hold it down for a couple seconds? (Make sure some windows are open)

Comment: Also, install Gnome Tweak tool. Under Keyboard  & Mouse -> Overview Shortcut -> Additional Layout Options. Explore that and see if left Alt is set to anything. It's possible that a "hide window on focus loss" setting is enabled, possibly because the Alt_L is activating the top bar.

Comment: Quick tap on left alt opens application menu. On holding alt active window losts focus. And I don't have any combinations with Alt